# Why are keyboard keys jumbled when logging into Mac via Windows VNC?

Tags: mac, keyboard

I am logging to a Mac 10.5.8 via Windows 7 VNC.

Keyboard on Windows is English. Keyboard on Mac is English.

Most keys work they way they are supposed to except these:

- Shift-7: should be & but is ?
- Shift-8: should be * but is (
- Shift-9: should be * but is )

However Shift 1-6 are fine.

There are a few other keys that are jumbled as well.

When I log into the MAC without VNC it works fine.

**How can I get the keyboard to function properly on the Mac when logged in via VNC?**

Comment: I (hopefully) will be doing something very similar to this soon only with Windows XP, so I'll let you know if I encounter the same problem -- and perhaps how to solve it.

Comment: good luck: now I can't even type anything, when I try, it just shows a question mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac & Windows have different keyboard mappings, the program I'm working on tackles this problem programmatically maybe there is a similar feature in the program you're using....